# Is it possible to extend support for Kannada language in Orchard CMS

Tags: javascript, jquery, orchardcms, multilingual, orchardcms-1.8

Is it possible to extend support for Kannada language in Orchard CMS?
Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Also, is it possible to show language specific editors like baraha/ nudi 
in Orchard CMS?

Comment: What do you mean by support? You can set up a proper culture code to kn-IN in site settings to have .NET use culture-specific settings. I don't think non-unicode languages will be ever supported ootb, as they most likely would require some external conversion software: http://cis-india.org/openness/blog/converting-from-non-unicode-nudi-baraha-font-encoding-to-unicode-kannada But I'm not a specialist here and maybe someone has done that as a module.

Comment: Thanks for the information Piotr. When I referred the link https://crowdin.com/project/orchard-cms, I could not find a mention for kannada language and hence wanted to know if articles in this language can still be managed on orchard. Sorry, I haven't used Orchard CMS and have no idea about it. I wanted to know about its capabilities before committing to the clients.